# Firebase ValueEventListener not triggered when attached to DatabaseReference

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database. I can write to the database without any problems however I can not read from it. I read on the docs that adding a ValueEventListener will trigger when attached and every time the data changes in the db. However, my onDataChanged Method never fires.

My code is shown below:

```
patientReference = databaseReference.child("patients")
patientReference.addValueEventListener(profileListener);

private ValueEventListener profileListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       System.out.println("In onDataChange");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("inInCancelled");
    }
};
```

Neither of the `println` get executed. Not sure what is going wrong but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you changing the data under the top-level "patients" node?

Comment: It is very uncommon for a `ValueEventListener`'s `onDataChange` nor its `onCancelled` to be called. The only cases I can think of is if you have connectivity problems in your app. To troubleshoot that, I recommend [setting your log level to debug](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and checking the logcat output for hints.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have not changed the data yet, I am just trying to download the patients profile on the start of the app.